# Name this track

Tags: alan-wake

In the very beginning of the American Nightmare when you bring down the satellite and have to run through some fires. What is the name of this song?
All I can find online is Balance Slays the Demon, The Happy Song and track from final credits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try Club Foot by Kasabian?

Here's a youtube link: